# A bound on the $\mathrm{L}^p$ norm in terms of the $\mathrm{L}^2$ norm in periodic Sobolev spaces

Tags: inequality, fourier-series, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

**Preliminaries:** Given ${s \geq 0}$, let ${\mathrm{H}_P^s}$ denote the ${\mathrm{L}^2}$-based fractional-order Sobolev space of ${P}$-periodic functions on the line with norm
\begin{equation*}
\| u \|_{\mathrm{H}_P^s} = \left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigg(1 + \frac{4 \pi^2 n^2}{P^2}\bigg)^{s} |\widehat{u}_n|^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2},
\end{equation*}
where ${\widehat{u}}$ is the ${n}$th Fourier coefficient. We set ${\mathrm{L}_P^2 \equiv \mathrm{H}_P^0}$ and recall Parseval's theorem giving the equivalent $\mathrm{H}^s(-\frac{P}{2},\frac{P}{2})$ norm when $s$ is a nonnegative integer. Moreover, let ${\| \cdot \|_{\infty}}$ express the supremum norm on an interval of length ${P}$.

> **Question:** Fix ${s > \frac{1}{2}}$ and ${p > 2}$ and consider functions ${u}$ in an open ball of ${\mathrm{H}_P^s}$, that is, ${\| u
> \|_{\mathrm{H}_P^s} < R}$. Is it possible to estimate
>   \begin{equation*} \| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^p}^{p} := \int_{-\frac{P}{2}}^{\frac{P}{2}} u^{p} \,
>  \mathrm{d}x \lesssim \| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2}^{2 + \epsilon}
> \end{equation*} for some ${\epsilon > 0}$ (likely depending on ${p}$)?

**Ideas:** We have
\begin{equation*}
\| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^p}^{p} \leq \| u \|_{\infty}^{p - 2} \| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2}^{2},
\end{equation*}
so it is perhaps easiest to establish ${\| u \|_{\infty}^{p  - 2} \lesssim \| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2}^{\epsilon}}$.

> That is, do we have
>   $${\| u \|_{\infty} \lesssim \| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2}^{\tilde{\epsilon}}}$$
>   for some $\tilde{\epsilon} > 0$ given that ${\| u
> \|_{\mathrm{H}_P^s} < R}$?

When ${s = 1}$ this is true based on the estimate
\begin{equation}
\| u \|_{\infty} \lesssim \| u' \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2}^{\frac{1}{2}} \| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2}^{\frac{1}{2}} \lesssim \| u \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
(since ${\| u' \|_{\mathrm{L}_P^2} \leq \| u \|_{\mathrm{H}_P^1} < R}$). This estimate is found in these [[lecture notes, page 21]](http://math.cts.nthu.edu.tw/Mathematics/2012Summer-AIFD/Lecture%201.pdf) when the domain is the real line ${\mathbb{R}}$, but it would be nice to see an argument/reference to the periodic case. And does it extend to the general setting with $s > \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: [The solution is found on MathOverFlow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/211217/68629]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $s>1/2$ the norm of $H^s$ controls the $L^\infty$ norm. Indeed, when the series of Fourier coefficients is absolutely convergent, their sum bounds $\sup|u|$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\|u\|_{L^\infty}\le  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat u_n| \le 
C(s,P)
\left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigg(1 + \frac{4 \pi^2 n^2}{P^2}\bigg)^{s} |\widehat{u}_n|^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2}
$$
where
$$
C(s,P) =  \left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigg(1 + \frac{4 \pi^2 n^2}{P^2}\bigg)^{-s} \right)^\frac{1}{2} <\infty $$
is a finite constant.

You can then use the [log-convexity of the $L^p$ norm](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/#log-convex) to bound $L^p$ norm in terms of $L^2$ and $L^\infty$.

Comment: This argument gives $\epsilon = 0$, but I need $\epsilon > 0$. I think the solution is to get some estimate involving derivatives, as in the $s = 1$ case above, but the details are unclear.